# PostgreSQL: Combining table columns to create a timestamp

Tags: database, postgresql, timestamp

I have 5 separate columns containing time information in table 'Information':
column name {format e.g.}(variable type)

```
day {Fri}(Varchar)
month {Apr}(Varchar)
date {18}(Varchar)
time {22:59:30}(Varchar)
year {2014}(Varchar)
```

How do I create another column in the table with the timestamp of most of these combined variables?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate values into a string, then cast it to timestamp.

```
select (month || ' ' || date || ', ' || year || ' ' || time)::timestamp
```

This assumes that the concatenation results in a valid timestamp. Since all your columns are defined as VARCHAR, I think it's unlikely to work right the first time. You'll probably have to fix some bad data.

After it works, you should probably extract the day of the week from the result, and compare it to the column "day". If they're not the same, you have another problem to fix.

Think hard about storing actual timestamps instead of pieces.